# The working directory does not exist in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

I wanted to study some code that dumps relevant data in a database, find out how it works and adapt it to my own version.

I only got as far as loading the solution in VS 2010, hitting the "Start Debugging" button, and then I got this error:

```
The working directory does not exist:
'D:\Dev\CodeProject\articles\smartcardfmwk\Smartcard_Framework
```

How can I fix this error?

The source code in question is [Smart Card Framework, from Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16653/A-Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET?msg=4609259#xx4609259xx)

I downloaded the "Updated Project (VS2010)" and I can open it in VS2010, as well as build, but debugging just wouldn't work.

I did not try replicating the path yet, but as this is a working project, my company requires that it is placed on a very specific location accessible by others.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it. It was so simple, I'm sorry for wasting anyone's time.

The source Solution had a lot of Projects under them. I figured at least one of them was pointing to a directory that doesn't exist, so I waded through the Projects,

- I right-clicked a Project and clicked the Properties
- This will open up the ProjectName Property Tab
- Under the Debug tab, there is a filed called "Working Directory"; I changed it to where the project is currently located.

This solved my problem, for now, unless there's a Project I missed. I am wondering, though, if I have to do this again if I move the Solution elsewhere.

Comment: _I am wondering, though, if I have to do this again if I move the Solution elsewhere._ As far as I know this information is stored in `*.csproj.user` files that are local user setting files and should not be shared between the team members or different workstations. So on another workstation Working Directory should be empty by default (which means that no Working Directory would be specified so exe will use its current folder).  You should also exclude `.user` files from source control.

Comment: In my case wrong path was at Project properties -> Build tab -> Output path. It's completely incorrect behaviour of VS because `csproj` file had other path specified in `OutputPath` tag of the corresponding Configuration group.

Comment: You did not waste anybody's time. 6 years later I just had this problem and solved it quickly thanks to your post!

Answer (score 1):

This happened also in VS 2019 after importing / upgrading an old C# project. I was not able to see any project properties to change.
Finally it was fixed by manually editing the file `<ProjName>.user.csproj` as follows:

Replace

```
<StartWorkingDirectory>[wrong directory name]</StartWorkingDirectory>
```

with

```
<StartWorkingDirectory>.\</StartWorkingDirectory>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem that working directory does not exist, but I managed to solve it. There are certain steps to follow properly Whenever this error occurs.

1. In VS, open the "Project" at Toolbar.
2. Then go for Project properties.
3. Select Debug And check your working directory. If the path is wrong just browse it...

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me with VS 2022 when I right-clicked on a project (in Solution Explorer) and selected Rebuild.  Then following the answers here, I right-clicked and selected Properties / Deploy and found that the wrong Working Directory was specified there.  I emptied that textbox and tried Rebuild again -- same error (although, I am glad I removed that wrong path in that setting).  Then I tried right-click / Edit Project File, and within the setting PackageJsonDirectory, there it was again - the wrong Working Directory. I browsed to the correct directory within File Explorer (the directory that had the package.json file for my project) and copied the full path in the File Explorer Address bar into the PackageJsonDirectory setting within the Project File, and FINALLY right-click Rebuild worked.